# CSS image opacity only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a page at http://shivampaw.ml/blog

It has a header image and is using Wordpress. I am trying to make the header image slightly less opaque and set it to opacity: 0.6

However when I use:

```
site-header{
     opacity: 0.6;
}
```

It makes the entire div less opaque. I have researched and I don't think I can change the divs as they are using Wordpress.

How can I achieve this?

Is it also possible to make the background image fixed? Right now it repeats which means it has a weird colour change. I want to avoid that so can I make it fixed? I tried changing background-attachment but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try removing the background from .site-header, and then add the following pseudo classs as detailed [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/) and [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity)

```
.site-header {
   position:relative;
}

.site-header::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("./images/header.png");
  opacity: 0.6;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another `div` containing the image and setting the `div` `opacity` to `0.6` instead of setting a background image in the `css`.

Or, you could edit the image and set it's `opacity` to `60%` via an image editor tool such as `Photoshop`, `Gimp` or another one :)